# Ajax function makes the rest of the javascript get ignored

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

I need help solving a problem that I have and I could not solve. Im relatively new in the web development area and it is something that really interests me so I want to become good at it. I am trying to implement an ajax function in Javascript for my website. When I remove the ***showDetails()*** function, the rest of the Javascript runs perfectly. But when I implement the ***showDetails()*** function, everything else in the script gets ignored, like it's empty and there is only the ajax function inside. How can I get the rest of the code to get recognized? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
function showRegUsr() {

  if ($('#regUsr').is(':hidden')) {
    $("#regUsr").slideDown();
    $("#joinReq").slideUp();
    $("#searchBy").slideUp();
    document.getElementById("tabRegUsr").style.cursor = 'default';
    document.getElementById("tabJoinReq").style.cursor = 'pointer';
    document.getElementById("tabSearchBy").style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }
}

function showJoinReq() {

  if ($('#joinReq').is(':hidden')) {
    $("#joinReq").slideDown();
    $("#regUsr").slideUp();
    $("#searchBy").slideUp();
    document.getElementById("tabJoinReq").style.cursor = 'default';
    document.getElementById("tabSearchBy").style.cursor = 'pointer';
    document.getElementById("tabRegUsr").style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }
}

function showSearch() {

  if ($('#searchBy').is(':hidden')) {
    $("#searchBy").slideDown();
    $("#joinReq").slideUp();
    $("#regUsr").slideUp();
    document.getElementById("tabSearchBy").style.cursor = 'default';
    document.getElementById("tabJoinReq").style.cursor = 'pointer';
    document.getElementById("tabRegUsr").style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }
}



function showAll() {
  window.location.href = 'notes.php';
  //$("#searchAll").style.display = 'none';
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("joinReq").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("searchBy").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("moreTab").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("tabRegUsr").style.cursor = 'default';
  document.getElementById("tabJoinReq").style.cursor = 'pointer';
  document.getElementById("tabSearchBy").style.cursor = 'pointer';
};

function showDetails() {
  var idofclicked = (this.id);

  if ((idofclicked) != "" && (idofclicked) != "hide") {
    $('#moreTab').slideDown();
    $('#pinakas').slideUp();

  }
  if ((idofclicked) == "hide") {
    $('#moreTab').slideUp();
    $('#pinakas').slideDown();

  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'usersNewFunctions.php',
    data: 'func=showDetails&evID=' + idofclicked,
    success: function(msg) {
      var response = msg.split(';', 8);
      var var1 = response[0];
      var var2 = response[1];
      var var3 = response[2];
      var var4 = response[3];
      var var5 = response[4];
      var var6 = response[5];
      var var7 = response[6];
      var var8 = response[7];

      var var9 = "";

      if (var5 == 3) {
        var9 = "Admin";
      } else if (var5 == 2) {
        var9 = "Team Member";
      } else if (var5 == 1) {
        var9 = "Registered Guest";
      } else if (var5 == 0) {
        var9 = "Unregistered User";
      }

      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Name: " + var1;
      document.getElementById("surname").innerHTML = "Surname: " + var2;
      document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Username: " + var3;
      document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = "Email: " + var4;
      document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "Type: " + var9;
      document.getElementById("created_on").innerHTML = "Joined on: " + var6;
      document.getElementById("newsletter").innerHTML = "Newsletter: " + var7;
      document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = var8;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: `);` at the end doesn't have any matching `(`.

Comment: thank you very much!! yes it was that parenthesis and semicolon! The rest of the javascript is fully recognizable! My apologies and thank you for taking time to help me! :)